# Which kernel should I use for my hardware, oem or generic?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu

This is my system information:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.8 tk: Qt 5.12.8 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20T6S0UQ00 v: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20T6S0UQ00 serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: R1AET41W (1.17 ) 
  date: 11/11/2021 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 27.9 Wh condition: 40.1/45.0 Wh (89%) volts: 12.0/11.3 
  model: Celxpert 5B10X026 type: Li-poly serial: <filter> status: Unknown 
  cycles: 65 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 50302 
  Speed: 1396 MHz min/max: 1400/2100 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1397 
  2: 1403 3: 1397 4: 1396 5: 1397 6: 1396 7: 1397 8: 1397 9: 1397 10: 1397 11: 1397 
  12: 1397 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.0 
  chip ID: 1002:1636 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu FAILED: ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa compositor: kwin_x11 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0 5.13.0-30-generic LLVM 12.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.1 
  chip ID: 1002:1637 
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: N/A bus ID: 04:00.5 chip ID: 1022:15e2 
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 04:00.6 chip ID: 1022:15e3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-30-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 02:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 2000 
  bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 8086:2723 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 10.20 GiB (4.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-256G-1001 
  size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: 21160001 
  scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 50.77 GiB used: 10.16 GiB (20.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
  ID-2: swap-1 size: 7.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.6 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 41 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 0 
Repos:
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
  1: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
  2: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
  3: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
  4: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
  5: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
  6: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
  7: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
  9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
  10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list 
  1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
Info:
  Processes: 317 Uptime: 51m Memory: 7.00 GiB used: 3.39 GiB (48.4%) Init: systemd 
  v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  running in: konsole inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: With the current kernel do you have any errors or is anything not working?

Comment: Not now but when I installed ubuntu some months ago then I was having graphics issue, and someone on reddit suggested that generic kernel is too old for your hardware and you should upgrade the kernel to by `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04d`. So I thought just after installing kubuntu of doing that, but thought it would be better to ask to someone who knows the stuff.

Comment: If you have no errors I would not be changing the kernel. As for video issues maybe a kernel or maybe a different driver would be needed.